# What is a Data Factory Utillity

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm looking for a documentation regarding Data Factory Utility activities in SFMC and I can't find any description of its purpose. There's only how to set them up. Can anyone briefly explain it's usage? Is it possible to import data straight from SQL server using it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They're used to load and transform data from the SQL Server based environment of the Email App to the Oracle/Netezza environment that underlies Discover and Audience Builder. Basically, don't touch. Nothing happening. Move on.

Comment: This has now become one of my favorite answers ever on SFSE.

Comment: Yes this was indeed a fun answer, but could you provide a bit more? I too am puzzled by what exactly they do, and the documentation is of absolutely no use!

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Macca's answer, when contact deletion jobs are started in contact builder, it creates automation and data factory utility based on the criteria that you select. For eg., I asked all the unsubscribed contacts to be deleted and a DFU is created with 'unsubscribe' selected in it.[image]